# How to distribute workloads of k8s cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I am creating synthetic monitoring using Python's robot framework. I am triggering a cronjob every 5 minutes. This cronjob has 34 containers. My question is can I use any scaling mechanism where if the cronjob pod consumes all the node resources(CPU and memory) then it will use other node resources but don't start from the beginning? for example: if the the pod is running containers from 1 to 15 then it will scale to another pod and run the rest of the containers to finish the job.

Comment: I've implemented tasks like this using a job queue such as RabbitMQ, plus a long-running Deployment that does work from it.  There is no CronJob _per se_, the Deployment will start doing work whenever it appears in the queue.  You can then set up a HorizontalPodAutoscaler on the worker's CPU utilization, or (with possibly-complex additional setup) the queue length.

Comment: can you give me a full overview? right now I am just triggering the cronjob whenever a new deployment/build happens in a cluster. In your case what the architecture will look like? @DavidMaze

Comment: Do you mean you're running 34 pods or 34 containers? A single pod could have 34 containers, but the cluster can't schedule them separately if they are all bundled into a single pod, regardless of what resources are free.

Comment: I have a cronjob that has 34 containers. yes, so I am just thinking of breaking the containers down and scheduling them one by one. - @BlenderFox